# Converting strings in quotes to single phrase with Regular expression

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am working on tag recommendation and need to convert all words in quotes to a single phrase. For example

```
'In Absence of Good Men' to InAbsenceOfGoodMen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, using `re.sub` and a callback:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "'In Absence of Good Men'"
>>> re.sub("'(.*?)'", lambda x: x.group(1).replace(' ', ''), string)
'InAbsenceofGoodMen'
```

---

You can make this a bit more readable, by moving the lambda out into its own function:

```
def foo(m):
    if m:
        return m.group(1).replace(' ', '')

string = "'In Absence of Good Men'"
new_string = re.sub("'(.*?)'", foo, string)
```

You can catch non-matches and handle errors better this way.

Comment: Could you tell me what this group method is doing?

Comment: @SeemaMudgil Sure. The callback receives a `match` object. In order to extract the string that matched, you call `group(1)`. (1) in this case because there's a capturing group in the regex. If there is no match, `foo` receives `None`, so you need the `if` check.

Comment: One more thing. If I have to selectively do this based on number of white spaces in the string.. for example ` This will not work but you can try another ` , should not be converted to one phrase

Comment: @SeemaMudgil You can use `re.subn(pattern, foo, string, num_count)` where `num_count` is the number of substitutions you want to make.

Comment: @SeemaMudgil Here's the docs for what I just mentioned: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.subn

Comment: One quick help needed.. if i have a string  " British Prime Minister Theresa May closest advisers Nick Timothy and Fiona Hill have resigned following the Conservatives\' loss in the snap general elections held on Thursday."                                  I need to remove that escape sequence in "Conservatives\'" .. Could u please suggest ..                                  I tried using re.sub('\\', " ",x) . but didn't work out

Comment: @SeemaMudgil Try re.sub(r"\\", " ", x)? Treat it like a raw string. Else you'd need "\\\\".